# Why does my Shopify image and video gallery section not work?

Tags: json, shopify, liquid, shopify-template, liquid-template

I'm trying to build my first custom section for Shopify by following a tutorial on Skillshare.

I have followed as closely as possible, and was able to get the images and settings to appear in the theme's customizer.

However, since attempting to add video blocks as an option, my image blocks no longer appear.

The new video blocks appear to work, but the previously working image blocks are now not appearing.

I am able to select an image in the customizer, but they never actually appear on the page.

Is there an error in my code?

```
<div class="gallery">
{% for block in section.blocks %}
{% if block.type == "image" %}
<div class="image-wrap" style="background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '500x' }}');">
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if block.type == "video" %}

{% if block.settings.video_url == blank %}
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/pEa_F0xk_5k" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

{% else %}

{% if block.settings.video_url.type == "youtube" %}
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/{{ block.settings.video_url.id }}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
{% endif %}

{% if block.settings.video_url.type == "vimeo" %}
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ block.settings.video_url.id }}"></iframe>
{% endif %}

{% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}

</div>

{% schema %}
{
"name": "Gallery",
"settings": [
{
"type" : "select",
"id" : "per-row",
"label" : "Images per row",
"options" : [
{
"value" : "100%",
"label" : "1 per row"
},
{
"value" : "49.5%",
"label" : "2 per row"
},
{
"value" : "32.5%",
"label" : "3 per row"
},
{
"value" : "24.5%",
"label" : "4 per row"
},
{
"value" : "19.5",
"label" : "5 per row"
}
],
"default" : "49.5%"
},
{
"type" : "select",
"id" : "height",
"label" : "Image Height",
"options" : [
{
"value" : "300px",
"label" : "300px"
},
{
"value" : "400px",
"label" : "400px"
},
{
"value" : "500px",
"label" : "500px"
}
],
"default" : "500px"
}
],
"blocks" : [
{
"type" : "image",
"name" : "Image Block",
"settings" : [
{
"type" : "image_picker",
"id" : "image",
"label" : "Image"
}
]
},
{
"type" : "video",
"name" : "Video Block",
"settings" : [
{
"type" : "video_url",
"id" : "video_url",
"label" : "Video URL",
"accept" : ["youtube","vimeo"]
}
]
}
],

"presets": [
{
"name" : "Gallery"
}
]
}

{% endschema %}

{% style %}
.image-wrap  iframe {
display : inline-block;
width : {{ section.settings.per-row }};
height : {{ section.settings.height }};
background-size : cover;
}
{% endstyle %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

Comment: There is something wrong in the style. Maybe it was `.image-wrap, iframe` (note the `,`)

Answer (score 0):

Fabio is correct in suggesting it is a problem with the style you added.

When you added `iframe` beside `.image-wrap` without the comma you are targeting an iframe element inside an element with a class of image-wrap which doesn't correlate with your code. Having `.image-wrap, iframe` means target any class with `.image-wrap` and any iframe element.

To keep that css contained to the task, so it doesn't interfere with other iframes in your page you should wrap the css with a parent `.gallery iframe` or give your iframe a class and target it that way.